# Why does this improper integral converge

Tags: integration, complex-integration, cauchy-principal-value

I can't understand a part of a proof. Here is the strange part isolated.

Let $1<q<2$. Then

$(\int_{|z-\tau|\leq R}\frac{d\tau}{|z-\tau|^q})^q = (\frac{2\pi R^{2-q}}{2-q})^q$

The integral is over complex numbers. It seems to me that the integral diverges, but I suspect this has something to do with improper integrals. Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with them in this setting. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: That answer is correct for $1\le q\lt2$, but the integral does not converge for $q\ge2$.

Comment: I edited the question, that is what the proof actually stated. But I still can't see the answer.

Comment: Try substituting $\tau=w+z$ then converting to polar coordinates

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with complex integration or the Cauchy Principal Value. This is simply a 2 dimensional real integral.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. I had forgotten to apply the Jacobian. Yikes!